# Using check digit algorithm to determine whether a value inputed is valid?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing code for a form that is supposed to determine whether a value inputted by the user is valid as a check digit. They input a 13 digit number and it should determine whether or not the last value is valid as a check digit. I have written in the code for the check digit algorithm but I'm having trouble with comparing the value that the algorithm found with what the user input. I have tried using the substring method to compare the 13th number given by the user with the check digit that the algorithm determined but I am having issues with the syntax of everything.

This is the code I have been working on:

```
Private Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
    Dim intDigit As Integer
    Dim intTotalOdd As Integer
    Dim intTotalEven As Integer
    Dim intGrandTotal As Integer
    Dim intRemainder As Integer
    Dim intCheckDigit As Integer

    If txtNumber.Text.Length = 13 Then
        For intOdd As Integer = 1 To 11 Step 2
            intTotalOdd += (intDigit * 3)
        Next intOdd
        For intEven As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 2
            intTotalEven += intDigit
        Next intEven
        intGrandTotal = intTotalOdd + intTotalEven
        intRemainder = intGrandTotal Mod 10
        If intRemainder <> 0 Then
            intCheckDigit = 10 - intRemainder
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text.Substring(12, 13) = intCheckDigit Then
            lblStatus = "Valid"
        Else
            lblStatus = "Not Valid"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I think the way I'm doing it should work but I don't have very much to reference on how I would go about making the syntax work. Will the way that I'm trying to do it work or do I need to go about it in a different way?

Comment: What specific syntax issues are you having? I assume you want to write the final message to `lblStatus.Text`, not just `lblStatus`

Comment: @WillardSolutions Yes I had deleted the code above to try something else but entered it back in so the question would have better context but I seem to have forgotten to change the 'lblStatus' to 'lblStatus.Text'. The issue that I'm having is that I'm getting an error telling me that txtNumber.Text is not a string and I'm not sure that I can declare the text as a variable and I don't know what else I would do.

Comment: The snippet forgets to give intDigit a value, it is always 0.  Google "vb.net convert character to number" to get ahead.

Comment: I forgot once again to add a value to intDigit. Googling the conversion from character to a number doesn't help me. I need to declare the txtNumber as a string so I can use it in the substring but if I do that then I can't use txtNumber as I get the error "Text is not a member of String." I want to use another variable but then I can't use that variable to access the substring of the text.

Comment: If your error is that something isn't a atring, does a simple `.toString()` work for you?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I don't believe so. I need to compare the 13th number given by the user with the number the algorithm finds.

Comment: Can you add an example of a valid and invalid number so that if someone runs this to test it they can make sure it's working correctly?

Comment: Is the error on this line `If txtNumber.Text.Substring(12, 13) = intCheckDigit Then` ? I assume txtNumber is a TextBox. Yes? Then txtNumber.Text must be a String. Try `If txtNumber.Text.Substring(12, 13) = intCheckDigit.ToString Then`

Comment: intDigit never gets changed, so you're just adding 0 a bunch of times; and Substring() is supposed to get a start index and length, so Substring(12, 13) will throw an exception since it's looking for 13 characters starting at index 12...it should be Substring(12, 1) to get the 13th character. It's not clear what your algorithm is supposed to be doing, so hard to say why it might not be working besides that.